# gerrit fails to replicate repo to repo imported by gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gerrit

So I have a git repo created by gerrit and repo on a different machine that was imported by gitlab.

ssh has been set up for the gerrit user to the gitlab owner and ssh git@gitlab_vm logs that user in as git user.

But the replication fails with

```
[2017-04-07 17:28:41,128] [c9eb13f6] Replication to git@Gitlab_vm:groupname/gerrit-test.git started...
[2017-04-07 17:28:41,269] [c9eb13f6] Cannot replicate to git@Gitlab_vm:groupname/gerrit-test.git
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: git@Gitlab_vm:norricorp/gerrit-test.git: reject HostKey: Gitlab_vm
```

I have seen a few other answers on StackOverflow where setting StrictHostKeyChecking no works. But I still have same problems.

I have added the git user as gitlab user to the project. The replication has to go via gitlab rather than using git push or pull because of the pre-receive hook that gitlab adds to the repo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found http://markmail.org/message/icfo5j5wufzpadjc. I amended the known_hosts file for the gerrit user and then used ssh-keyscan to update the known_hosts.
Replication then no longer gives a "reject Hostkey" message in replication_log.